# Mocha, how to ignore node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I am trying to create a test environment which all source file is side by side with its test code. This is due to easy to track which file is without its test code. Below is the example of my directory after run build

```
built/api/a.js
built/api/a-test.js  
built/api/b.js
built/api/b-test.js
built/index.js
built/index-test.js
built/node_modules/...
built/package.json  
src/api/a.js
src/api/a-test.js
src/api/b.js
src/api/b-test.js
src/index.js
src/index-test.js
src/package.json
package.json
```

I am going to run my test by run 'npm test', below is my package.json content:

```
{ "name": "sample", 
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel ./src -d ./built && cd built && npm install",
    "test": "mocha built/**/*-test.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.0",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

My question is how can I skip those files in node_modules folder coincidently have name end with -test.js

Comment: Seems Mocha does not support it OOB, but couple of good ideas - https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1577

Comment: Generally you would run tests before the build step

Answer (score 11):

A little late to the party (13+ months!?), but...

Mocha doesn't support this out of the box. You need to use your glob-fu and get a little fancy. Running something like this on your command line should do the trick:

```
mocha './built/{,!(node_modules)/**}/*-test.js'
```

The glob pattern `{,!(node_modules)/**}` says

> Take entries in the current directory, or in any subdirectory of the current directory, regardless of depth, except for ones rooted in `./build/node_modules`.

Note that the single quotes are essentially *required* on OS X or Linux boxen. Left as a bareword (unquoted), or quoted with double quotes, you'll get shell globbing instead of the internal `glob()` used by `mocha`, so you're unlikely to get the results you might expect... unless you have an atypical shell.

The Windows shell only supports double quoting... and it doesn't have command line globbing, so on Windows, you'll probably want to leave this unquoted (but don't, err, *quote* me on that).

A better, more platform-agnostic way would be to put the glob pattern in your `test/mocha.opts` file, thus:

```
--require ./test/setup.js
--colors
--inline-diffs
./built/{,!(node_modules)/**}/*-test.js
```

Cheers!

Comment: To support Windows you’d probably want to use double quotes. How is that supposed to break on POSIX shells? As long as you don’t use `$` and take care with ``\`` in your argument, POSIX will pass it through just fine.

Comment: Windows package.json line:     "test": "mocha \"{,!(node_modules)/**}/*-test.js\""

Comment: Thank you @FelixEnescu, that works great for me. I only made one modifications which was `*-test.js` became `*.test.js` but this just comes down to your prefered naming convention :)

Answer (score 3):

```
mocha '**/*-test.js' --ignore 'built/node_modules/**/*'
```

Comment: Cool, but I prefer the glob pattern way that Nicholas provided, since that teaches us how to better use the CLI / is more command-independent.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to the existing answers... for those who use a mocha config file (`.mocharc.js`), you can include the `ignore` parameter:

```js
{
  ignore: 'built/node_modules/**/*'
}
```

Calling this with `mocha --config .mocharc.js built/**/*-test.js`